# Accessing raw conductivity data from capacitive touchscreen on Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, touchscreen

I am interested in the changes in conductivity measured by capacitive touchscreens on Android and iOS devices as they register touch inputs. Do either of these systems allow apps to access this data, or are you limited to only positional data on the screen where some threshold in conductivity is passed signaling a touch event?

I'm aware that at least on Android one can access pressure values from a MotionEvent, but I can't find any information about how exactly these pressure values are generated. Is it calculated from the relative change in capacitance/conductivity? The area of the touch event? Some combination of both?